# JMeter does not execute Java code correctly if it's ran as .jar file from command line

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm designing JMeter scenario which implies executing a certain .jar file via OS Process Sampler element. My Java code has while loop which basically checks a certain mailbox for a letter with a certain subject. Loop waits until finds one (emails are always delivered with roughly 3 minutes delay), parses it and writes some data to .txt file.

If I run this .jar directly from cmd then the code works as expected. But if I run it via JMeter OS Process Sampler then it never creates a file for me. I do see that email is delivered to inbox, so expect it to be parsed and .txt created.

At first I suspected that JMeter finishes Java scenario without waiting for while loop to execute. Then I put OS Process Sampler in a separate Thread and added a huge delay for this thread in order to wait and make 100% sure that email is delivered and Java only need to parse it but it does not help.

View Results Tree never shows any errors.

Here is my OS Process Sampler: https://www.screencast.com/t/LomYGShJHAkS

This is what I execute via cmd and it works as expected: java -jar mailosaurJavaRun.jar email533.druzey1a@mailosaur.in

And here is my code (it does not looks good but it works):

```
public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MailosaurHelper ms = new MailosaurHelper();
        String arg1 = ms.getFirstLinkInEmail(args[0]);

        BufferedWriter output = null;
        try {
            File file = new File("url.txt");
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            output.write(arg1);
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
          if ( output != null ) {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        }
    }
}

public class MailosaurHelper {

    protected final String API_KEY = "b3e4d2b193b5eb2";
    protected final String MAILBOX_ID = "d1uzey1a";

    public MailboxApi getEmailBox() {
        return new MailboxApi(MAILBOX_ID, API_KEY);
    }

    public String getFirstLinkInEmail(String email) {
        MailosaurHelper ms = new MailosaurHelper();
        String link = "";

        if (link.equals("") || link.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                link = ms.getAllEmailsByReceipent(email)[0].html.links[0]
                        .toString();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return link;
    }

    public Email[] getAllEmailsByReceipent(String recepient) {
        try {
            int ifArrayIsEmpty = getEmailBox().getEmailsByRecipient(recepient).length;
            while (ifArrayIsEmpty == 0) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    ifArrayIsEmpty = getEmailBox().getEmailsByRecipient(
                            recepient).length;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (MailosaurException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Email[] listOfEmails = null;
        try {
            listOfEmails = getEmailBox().getEmailsByRecipient(recepient);
        } catch (MailosaurException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listOfEmails;
    }
```

The bottom line is that I need to parse Mailosaur email, retrieve URL from it and use it further. Any other suggestion on how to do that using Jmeter/Java/Mailosaur are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need cmd in here, but if you're adamant to stick with it - use `/C` key when you call it.

Then, are your sure you're looking for your file in the right place?
According to documentation:

> By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative
>   pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named
>   by the system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in
>   which the Java virtual machine was invoked.

Check it thoroughly, BTW - you should see it in your sampler result.